# Does a multiclassed rogue/barbarian get sneak attack almost always?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, rogue, sneak-attack, barbarian

The rogue gets a sneak attack on attacks where you have advantage.

Barbarians have advantage on attacks using strength with the reckless attack feature, which doesn't seem to have a limit on usage.

Does that mean I would be able to use the sneak attack on every attack using strength?

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, a barbarian can use *reckless attack* to get sneak attack every turn if they want

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or ranged weapon.

Whenever you have advantage, you can apply sneak attack as long as you are  attacking with a finesse or ranged weapon. The source of the advantage does not matter at all.

> ... you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength during this turn.

If you use *reckless attack* using strength with a finesse melee weapon, you can apply sneak attack to one attack every turn. However, this does give opponents advantage to hit you until your turn comes again.